# Cakephp - Getting items from next page in current page?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm currently working on a gallery system using cakephp. In it, we have paginated each image album so each page contains a set number of images at most. I have attained this by using:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Item.album_id' => $id
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'Item.added' => 'desc'
    ),
    'limit' => '50'
);
```

On my view controller. With this, I can show all the items on each page with no problems.

I'm currently, however, facing a single issue: I need to show, after all the items in the current page, a button that leads to the next page. This is not a problem, except that by design the button that says NEXT PAGE should have an item from the next page as its background.

I have looked around, trying to figure out a way to pull an item from the next page of a paginated system in cakephp without luck. Has anyone done this, or does anyone have a clue how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query the preview image manually in the current page.
To access the page number you can use [$this->params](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) in the action. Then you have to query images with 'limit' and 'page' parameters as mentioned in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).
After that set the image URL like this:

```
$this->set('preview_image_url', $queried_url);
```

Then in the view use inline styling to set the background for the next button.

Answer (score 0):

With Alto's help, I ended up doing this (Putting it here just in case anyone wonders exactly how I did it):

```
$CurrPage = $this->params['paging']['Item']['page'];

$NextParams = array(
    'limit' => 1,
    //'page' => $CurrPage + 1,
    'order' => array(
        'Item.added' => 'desc'
    ),
    'offset' => $CurrPage*50
    //'order' =>('rand()')
);
$NextImage = $this->Item->find('first', $NextParams);

$this->set('NextImage', $NextImage);
```

This gives me the first item from the following page, which is good enough for me. Note the commented `'order' =>('rand()')` - I tried to grab a random item from the following page but, alas, it seems like Cake first scrambles all items and THEN paginates. There's probably a way around this, but for now this one did it for me.

Also, using `'page' => $CurrPage + 1` didn't seem to work, with the system instead returning a seemingly randomly chosen image. That's why I instead defaulted to using `'offset' => $CurrPage*50`, where 50 is the amount of items per page I'm showing.